# Property 'trace' does not exist on type 'typeof NxWelcomeService'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, service, monorepo, typeof, nomachine-nx

I am migrating my project to Nx Monorepo and it happens that libraries that worked fine in my project outside of Nx do not recognize public methods here.
It doesn't happen only with libraries, I have created a simple component and service to test and it throws the same error
This is the code
nx-welcome.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NxWelcomeService } from './nx-welcome.service' 

@Component({
  selector: 'linde-tgv-nx-welcome',
  templateUrl: './nx-welcome.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class NxWelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  };
  private logger = NxWelcomeService
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.logger.trace('checklist-app - NxWelcomeComponent')
  }
}
```

nx-welcome.component.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NxWelcomeService {

  constructor() { }
  
  public trace(message :string) {console.log(message)}
}
```

tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@linde-tgv/generated/linde-api-types": [
        "libs/generated/linde-api-types/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@tgv/logger": ["libs/tgv-logger/src/index.ts"],
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib/my-lib",
        "dist/my-lib"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.editor.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with NX.
I had defined

```
private logger = NxWelcomeService
```

rather than

```
constructor(private logger: NxWelcomeService)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try importing as a injectable, inside the constructor.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NxWelcomeService } from './nx-welcome.service' 

@Component({
  selector: 'linde-tgv-nx-welcome',
  templateUrl: './nx-welcome.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class NxWelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private logger: NxWelcomeService) {
  };
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.logger.trace('checklist-app - NxWelcomeComponent')
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, Naren... the error persists.
And also "No suitable injection token for parameter 'logger' of class 'NxWelcomeComponent. (-992003)"

Comment: @Nestor have you tried adding NxWelcomeService inside the providers array of a module? could you also check by adding it to the providers array of the component decorator `@Component({
  selector: 'linde-tgv-nx-welcome',
  templateUrl: './nx-welcome.component.html',
  styles: [],
providers: [NxWelcomeService]
})`